# Authentication with Ember.js 2.x

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth, form-authentication

I'm new to ember.js and I find it pretty confusing to figure out which is a good way for authentication (version 2.x) since most of the examples on the web seem to be outdated. Also the documentation often doesn't come with easy to understand beginner examples.

Right now I'm following [this](http://blog.willrax.com/oauth-with-firebase-and-ember/http://blog.willrax.com/oauth-with-firebase-and-ember/) tutorial. The initializer works apparently, I can also trigger the action `login` but then it gets stuck on the `controller.get` bit. The console spits out a `TypeError: controller.get(...) is undefinedTypeError: controller.get(...) is undefined`.

**app/components/login-form**

```
  ...
  actions: {                   
    login: function() {        
      var controller = this;   
      controller.get("session").login().then(function(admin) {
        // Persist your users details.  
      }, function() {
        // User rejected authentication request
      });
    } 
  }
  ...
```

**app/templates/components/login-form**

```
<form {{action 'login' on='submit'}}> 
  <div class="form-group">     
    <label for="email">Login</label>
    {{input value=email placeholder='Enter Login' class='form-control'}}
  </div>                       
  <div class="form-group">     
    <label for="password">Password</label> 
    {{input value=password placeholder='Enter Password' class='form-control' type='password'}}
  </div>                       
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
</form>
```

**app/templates/admin.hbs**

```
<div class="page-header">      
  <h1>Login</h1>               
</div>
{{login-form}}
```

I hope somebody can point me into the right direction to get this working. I'd also appreciate any general advice where to find good examples or explanations concerning the ember 2.x way of authentication.

**Edit**: I need to have this working with Firebase.

Comment: May I recommend https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth

Comment: I had a look on that one but I wasn't sure how compatible or easy to setup it would prove with Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

http://ember-simple-auth.com/

looks like your best bet. They have a good video on setting it up too.
For connection to firebase you could create backend to authenticated with and have that check firebase. I'm using express and jwt in node.js to communicate with my  mongoDB database.